# Solution for payment process required

Tags: paypal, payment, payment-processing

We have the following requirements for an online payment solution:

- There are two types of users: Buyers and sellers.
- Only digital stuff is exchanged.
- When a buyer buys content, money is sent to the seller immediately as well as a small fraction of the money to the website owners.
- A buyer must before he can sell his offerings connect his account (that may be PayPal or any other service) to the platform to be able to receive money.

Now, I'm not an expert in this field but my initial idea was to have a PayPal account with Mass Transactions enabled for this website which will receive all payments and then send money out to the sellers via API calls.

However, it would be very nice if it is possible to make this process completely external, a.k.a. use a service for payment which sends the bulk of the money to the seller but a small fraction to the shareholders (website owners). Of course, a seller must first connect his account to the platform to make sure in case one of his offerings was bought he can receive money.

Any ideas are well appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPal Adaptive Payments/Chained Payments might be the best option for you as it can be setup to automatically send a portion of your payments to other accounts.

Here is the overview of Adaptive Payments: 
[Adaptive Payments Overview](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/gs_AdaptivePayments)

From the PayPal Documentation here is an exact definition of Chained Payments:

Chained payments allow a sender to send a single payment to a primary receiver. The primary receiver keeps part of the payment and pays secondary receivers the remainder. For example, your application could be an online travel agency that handles bookings for airfare, hotel reservations, and car rentals. The sender sees only you as the primary receiver. You allocate the payment for your commission and the actual cost of services provided by other receivers. PayPal then deducts money from the sender’s account and deposits it in both your account and the secondary receivers’ accounts.

Here is the information on Chained Payments:
[Chained Payment Developer Guide](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_dev_Datasheet_APC_R3.pdf)

Here is information on registering your Application, which will allow you to create the Sandbox API Calls:

[PayPal APP Basics](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/lifecycle/apps101)